# Benefit of saving merkle root in bitcoin block headers

Tags: bitcoin, merkle-tree

Is there any benefit of saving merkle root in bitcoin block headers?
Is it better than saving a sha256 hash of block data?
If it just detects blockwise corruption, merkle root seems to have no benefit over saving simple single hash value.

It's a simple question but difficult to find a clear answer.

Comment: You should read about [Simplified Payment Verification](https://wiki.bitcoinsv.io/index.php/Simplified_Payment_Verification#Merkle_Trees.2C_Merkle_Roots.2C_Merkle_Paths_and_Merkle_Proofs).